# AngularJS $http.delete somehow redirecting to GET method of REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, express, webkit.net

Here is where I am calling the method:

```
$http.delete(BaseUrl + '/conversations/' + $scope.conversation.id,{headers:reqHeaders}).
        success(function(data,status){
            $scope.wtf = data;
        }).
        error(function(err){
            $scope.wtf = err;
        });
```

The REST service is built on Express/Node.js. I have another app (built with Backbone) using the service, including this delete method, without a problem.

From the server log it looks like the DELETE request is coming in followed by a GET. It almost looks like the pre flight OPTIONS request is coming in as DELETE and is followed by GET instead. There is obviously something I'm missing but I can't put my finger on it. Anyone have any thoughts?

EDIT: I am encountering this problem with the app running in a [webkit.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/) embedded browser control. The DELETE request works fine in a proper browser.

Comment: i would start by trying $http['delete'](...) although checking out what the browser sends (firebug) would really clear things out

Comment: Trying it out with firebug in a proper browser I found that the DELETE request works. The problem is apparently with the embedded browser control I have to use.

Comment: you can use [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to monitor the request your control sends and the response from the server.

Comment: Tried fiddler for a few minutes this morning but wasn't able to see the traffic from the browser control for some reason. I don't really have time to keep fiddling (_haha_) with it so I'm just going to send a POST with {action:'delete'} and handle it on the server side. Hopefully I'll have time to revisit this and do it properly eventually.

Comment: Yeah... fiddler hooks into your system's proxy settings so you have to make sure your control takes into account those. Wireshark maybe? (just kidding). Good luck.